# How to ignore case in c# when searching

Tags: c#, string

I have this code that searches a list and returns the title if it matches the search word, but currently if I try searching for 'Test', it does not return the result. As in the list, is it 'test'.

Please assist.

```
try
{
    objCurrentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    objSSList = objCurrentWeb.Lists["Sales Materials"];

    foreach (SPListItem objSSListItem in objSSList.Items)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"]).Contains(searchWord))
        {
            resultLabel.Text = objSSListItem["Title"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    resultLabel.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"]).ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper())
```

or

```
ToLower()
```

both will work.

Comment: it doesnt work as resultLabel.Text.ToUpper() gives a red underline.

Comment: if (Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"]).ToUpper().Contains(searchWord)).ToUpper()

Comment: @DwayneJohnson - the code you posted above has the `ToUpper()` in the wrong place, it needs to be right after the searchWord variable not the `))`

Comment: @Hogan but why  if (Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"]).Contains(searchWord, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )) 
 doesnt work as well?

Comment: Because Contains does not take two arguments... no idea what @COLDTOLD is talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `ToLower` will not work with some languages.

Comment: @BrunoLM - I don't understand, the question is not about all programming languages, it is about C#

Answer (score 9):

You can check if a string is contained in another using `IndexOf`, then you can specify the `StringComparison` method and tell it to ignore CaseSensitivity.

```
(Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"])
    .IndexOf(searchWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) >= 0
```

To make it look better and easier to call, put it as an extension method

```
public static class StringExtender
{
    public static bool Contains(this string s, string str, StringComparison comparer)
    {
        return s.IndexOf(str, comparer) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution I expect, but I'm not sure it is "better" looking.  Wrapping this in an extension of string is probably the sexiest.  I'm amused that the wrong answer has 1 vote, and mine and yours that work have -2 and 0.

Comment: @Hogan Yep, I agree. I already had this code here, I should have posted earlier.

Answer (score 3):

another option is using Regular expressions

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("Arch",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (pattern.IsMatch("string to search"))
    Console.WriteLine("Match found");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Convert.ToString(objSSListItem["Title"]).Contains(searchWord, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase ))
```

try it, it should ignore the case

Comment: Contains only takes one arguement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: This code is invalid, unless you have an extension method that you didn't post.

Comment: yes you might add the following extension in case it not working at all for you to modify contains                                  `public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp) {
  return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}  `  reference from here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 0):

You may write your own comparer! (Just implement IComparer interface!)

More ways to do it?